# Laravel request unknown number of validate parameters

Tags: laravel

I have 3 parameters that I send through request body. 
At least one of them is necessary, others are optional, but it could be all 3 that would be send.

How should I validate this data? `sometimes` rule helps with optional parameters but how do I define that at least 1 is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`required_without`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without) as

```
$request->validate([
    'first' => 'required_without:second,third',
    'second' => 'required_without:first,third',
    'third' => 'required_without:first,second',
]);
```

In this way you can validate at least one from three fields among (`first`,`second` and `third`)

Explanation  of

```
'first' => 'required_without:second,third',
```

`first` must be present in absence or if empty of both `second` and `third`